# Preserving clip size in Montage

Tags: perl, image-processing, imagemagick, perlmagick

I am using PerlMagick and I am having 4 clipped images of various sizes,

Sizes are 25x25, 32x32, 40x40, 50x50

And I am creating a montage out of this, using simple Read command and Montage.

But when I use Montage, somehow all the Images are made to Uniform size, I think to the Maximum size, that is, 50x50.

How can I stop PerlMagick`s Montage from re-sizing.

I already tried, geometry => '+1+1' and geometry => '1x1<+1+1'

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `geometry` for montage is the size of each tile. So, you can try not specifying the geometry at all. If that doesn't work, you can can make some extra blank 50x50 images, composite the 25x25, 32x32, and 40x40 images on top of the blanks and then montage those; essentially you'd just make everything the same size (without scaling) and be done with it.

ImageMagick: great tool, somewhat odd API though.